# SQL Ranking based on value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create some ranking based on a value inside of my results.
My table consists of ID of job, date, and status name.
I am trying to create three additional fields of "Desired Group", "Desired Rank", and "Date Diff". I am trying to use the word "Re-Initiated" from the StatusName column to restart the clock on when I measure the date diff. The final goal is to get date diff field working based on the grouping/ranking.

So, the first "Re-Initiated" happened on July 22 and the response also happened on July 22 - so the date diff is zero. The second "Re-Initiated" happened on 9/23 and the last response was on 9/26 for a date diff of 3 days.

Any ideas would be wonderful!!

```
ID  Date    StatusName  Desired Group   Desired Rank    Date Diff
213 7/22/15 Re-Initiated    1           1   
213 7/22/15 Outside of Area 1           2               0
213 9/23/15 Re-Initiated    2           1   
213 9/24/15 Sent to Field   2           2   
213 9/26/15 No Cost Share   2           3               3
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using `SqlServer`,  `MySql` ?

Comment: Please edit your post and include [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) to solve this

Comment: Hello Juan -  I am using SQL Server. Thank You.

Comment: @April Version is also important 2005, 2008, 2014

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the desired group as a cumulative sum.  The rank and diff then come from that:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by date) as rnk,
       datediff(day, min(date) over (partition by id, grp), date) as diff
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when statusname = 'Re-Initiated' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that this puts the difference in dates on every row.  You can use a case statement if you want it only for certain rows.

Comment: Im always interested in looking your work. The only think is didnt run on my 2008 server looks like need something from 2012+ for the comulative `SUM`.  But in the [**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/474ff/2) run great

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Cumulative sums are (alas) only available in SQL Server 2012 and onwards.  In SQL Server 2008, you can replace the subquery with `outer apply` and calculate the group in the subquery.  An alternative method is a difference of row numbers approach.  You seem pretty knowledgeable, so I'll leave you with those hints so you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server can use `Partion By` and `Row_number()`

- `withRN`: Create a rowID
- `groupStart`: Calculate what rowID start a new group
- `goupRange`: Calculate from what ranges conform each group
- `previousStep`: Calculate the Group and Ranks
- `lastStep`: Calculate the difference between days for each group.
- Final query join `previousStep` and `lastStep`

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/474ff/4)

```
WITH withRN AS (
    SELECT [ID], [Date], [StatusName], [DesiredGroup], [DesiredRank], [DateDiff], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (ORDER BY [DATE], CASE WHEN [StatusName] = 'Re-Initiated' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as RN
    FROM Table1
),
groupStart AS (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RN) groupID
    FROM withRN T1
    WHERE T1.[StatusName] = 'Re-Initiated'
),
groupRange AS (
    SELECT G1.RN as rnStart, G2.RN  rnEnd, G1.groupID
    FROM groupStart G1
    LEFT JOIN groupStart G2
      ON G1.groupID = G2.groupID - 1
),
previousStep AS (
    SELECT W.ID, W.[Date], W.[StatusName], W.[DesiredGroup], W.[DesiredRank], W.[DateDiff], W.RN, G.groupID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.groupID ORDER BY W.[Date]) as DesireRank2
    FROM withRN W
    INNER JOIN  groupRange G
      ON W.RN >= G.rnStart
     AND W.RN < CASE 
                  WHEN G.rnEnd IS NULL THEN 999999999999
                  ELSE G.rnEnd
                END
),
lastStep AS (
   SELECT groupID, DATEDIFF ( dd, MIN([Date]), MAX([Date])) as dayD , MAX(RN) as diffRow
   FROM previousStep
   GROUP BY groupID
)
SELECT P.ID, P.[Date], P.[StatusName], P.[DesiredGroup], P.[DesiredRank], P.[DateDiff], P.groupID, P.DesireRank2, L.dayD
FROM previousStep P
LEFT JOIN lastStep L
  ON P.RN = L.diffRow
```

Comment: You might be interested in a simpler way to formulate the answer.  See my answer.

Comment: Thank you Juan. I could not get your solution to work but I really appreciate the time you took to work on it.

Comment: Gordon - the date diff did not work but it looks like your two groupings worked!! I should be able to use these to loop around to get the date diff by using a combination of the grp and the mk.

Comment: Gordon, I actually see what your date diff is doing once I stared at it for a bit. I am just going to loop around to get the max. I spent hours trying to do online searches and this is my first time using this type of blog for help. (I have been in Reporting for about 10 years). So, I can't tell you what a relief it is to have people to take the time to help. Thank you!!

Comment: @April You should comment on Gordon answer so he so he get a notification and can read your message. Or write using `@GordonLinoff`

Comment: @April I Fix my code now last 3 column have the exact answer you request.